# How to refer to element using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to get the value that is already existing in HTML element and pass it to another using jQuery. I ma not sure if I am referring to the element incorrectly as it returns Not a number value. Can you please look at my code and help:

```js
var oldPrice = parseFloat(jQuery('.product-price-worth .price .price').first().text().replace(/[^0-9\.]+/g, ""), 10);

$('div.ratio-div').html('<p>Now ' + oldPrice + '</p>');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="regular-price" itemprop="offers" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer">
    
        <link itemprop="availability" href="http://schema.org/InStock" content="In Stock">
        <span id="product-price-12674" class="product-price-worth">
            <span class="symbol-block">
                                    <span class="price-comment">Now</span>
<span class="currency-symbol">£</span>
</span>
<span itemprop="price">
                <span class="price"><span class="currency"></span>169</span>
</span>
</span>


</span>

<div class="ratio-div">&nbsp;</div>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nqo6n8e6/2/)

Comment: Are you trying to get the 169 value back as the oldPrice?

Comment: Yes, that is what I am trying to achieve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is perfect, but you use two class as same name (.price) in jquery.
Try this:

```js
var oldPrice = parseFloat(jQuery('.product-price-worth      .price').first().text().replace(/[^0-9\.]+/g, ""), 10);

     $('div.ratio-div').html('<p>Now ' + oldPrice + '</p>');
```

```html
<span class="regular-price" itemprop="offers" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer">
    
        <link itemprop="availability" href="http://schema.org/InStock" content="In Stock">
        <span id="product-price-12674" class="product-price-worth">
            <span class="symbol-block">
                                    <span class="price-comment">Now</span>
<span class="currency-symbol">£</span>
</span>
<span itemprop="price">
                <span class="price"><span class="currency"></span>169</span>
</span>
</span>


</span>

<div class="ratio-div">&nbsp;</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var oldPrice = parseFloat(jQuery('.product-price-worth [itemprop="price"] .price').first().text().replace(/[^0-9\.]+/g, ""), 10);
$('div.ratio-div').html('<p>Now ' + oldPrice + '</p>');
```

you need to use the attribute selector there, edited `[itemprop="price"]` as you have used itemprop as an attribute before class price element.
https://jsfiddle.net/nqo6n8e6/3/

Answer (score 1):

```
oldprice = jQuery('.product-price-worth span.price').text();
oldprice = parseFloat(oldprice.replace(/[^0-9\.]+/g, ""), 10);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you add an `id` to the span with the price class like this:

```
<span class="price" id="oldPrice"><span class="currency"></span>169</span>
```

Then you could get the value back like this:

```
var oldPrice = parseFloat($('#oldPrice').text());
```

Answer (score 0):

Your first `.price` in the selector

```
'.product-price-worth .price .price'
```

does not exist as the span is

```
<span itemprop="price">
```

you can:

- change the selector to:

  '.product-price-worth [itemprop="price"] .price'
- change the span to
- remove one the `.price` completely as [space] in a selector means any child at any level, not just direct descendents

  '.product-price-worth .price'

Updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/nqo6n8e6/4/